# React Hooks: how to update state variable based on another state variable update

Tags: reactjs

I've this code:

```
const drawLine = (x: number, y: number) => {
    setLineCord((prevCords) => [...prevCords, x, y])

    if (lineCord.length > 2) {
      setEdges((prevLines) => [
        ...prevLines,
        {
          points: lineCord,
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 2,
        },
      ])
      setLineCord((prev) => [])
    }
  }
```

basically when I call this function, I add two new elements to the array `LineCord` which is defined as a variable in the component state. after that I want to use the new `LineCord` array and do some logic (the code inside the if statement) based on the length of the array.

The problem is, the code inside the `if` statement doesn't execute after the `setLineCord` because of the fact that react hooks run asynchronously, so that when I check its length it will still be less that 2 even though I've added two new elements (x and y).

One solution I've tried is to use react `useEffect` and set `LineCord` as a dependency. that works totally fine, but I'm wondering if there exist a better solution for problems like this where I've to update a state variable and use it's new value somewhere after it's updated.

Comment: I would go the `useEffect` route, it's a side effect after all.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Even if I remove the if statement, the code below it isn't executed because `setLineCord` is asnyc function and if I console.log the `LineCord` after the state update it will remain in its previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new constant and use that instead of your state variable immediately after updating it's value

Try something like below:-

```
const drawLine = (x: number, y: number) => {
    const updatedLineCord = [...lineCord, x, y]
    setLineCord([...updatedLineCord])

    if (updatedLineCord.length > 2) {
      setEdges((prevLines) => [
        ...prevLines,
        {
          points: updatedLineCord,
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 2,
        },
      ])
      setLineCord([])
    }
  }
```